# How do I bubble up a non asynchronous error

Tags: javascript, try-catch, es6-promise

I'm trying to bubble up an error that comes from the verify function in jsonwebtoken, however, it wraps it in another Internal 500 Status error, rather than an Unauthorized error, that I want it to be.
Most of the components are built in loopback-next authentication components. The class below is a provider for a class called AuthenticationStrategy. AuthenticationStrategy is just a class with a passport strategy that returns an Authentication Strategy, which is passed on the metadata of a route. In the class below (the provider of type Authentication strategy, value() is the function returned when calling the provider. The passport strategy verification function has to first be converted to an Authentication strategy first, then returned through the value function to the Provider. When value() is called, the verify function runs on the metadata of the route, in this case, the bearer token. The Function cb below is the same as the 'done' function in a normal passport strategy, and returns (error, object), respectively

```
 import {AuthenticateErrorKeys} from '../error-keys';
import {RevokedTokenRepository, UserRepository} from '../../../repositories';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {Strategy} from 'passport-http-bearer'
import {HttpErrors} from '@loopback/rest';
import {StrategyAdapter} from '@loopback/authentication-passport'
import {AuthenticationStrategy} from '@loopback/authentication'
import {inject, Provider} from '@loopback/context'
var verify = require('jsonwebtoken').verify

export const BEARER_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'bearer';
export class PassportBearerAuthProvider implements Provider<AuthenticationStrategy> {
  constructor(
    @repository(RevokedTokenRepository)
    public revokedTokenRepository: RevokedTokenRepository,
      @repository(UserRepository)
    public userRepository: UserRepository,
  ){}
  value(): AuthenticationStrategy {
      const bearerStrategy = new Strategy(this.verify.bind(this));
      return this.convertToAuthStrategy(bearerStrategy);
  }

   async verify (token: string, cb: Function){
     try{
      if (token && (await this.revokedTokenRepository.get(token))) {
          throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(AuthenticateErrorKeys.TokenRevoked);
        }

        const userAuthToken = await verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string, {
          issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
        })

        let authUser = await this.userRepository.getAuthUser(userAuthToken.id)
        return cb(null, authUser)
      }
      catch(error) {
        if (error.name && error.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
          return cb(new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(AuthenticateErrorKeys.TokenInvalid), null)
        }
        if (error.name && error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
          return cb(new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(AuthenticateErrorKeys.TokenExpired), null)
        }
        if (error.code && error.code === "ENTITY_NOT_FOUND") {
          return cb(new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(`${AuthenticateErrorKeys.UserDoesNotExist}, id: ${error.entityId}`), null)
        }
        return cb(error, null)
      }
     }


  // Applies the `StrategyAdapter` to the configured basic strategy instance.
  // You'd better define your strategy name as a constant, like
  // `const AUTH_STRATEGY_NAME = 'basic'`
  // You will need to decorate the APIs later with the same name
  convertToAuthStrategy(bearer: Strategy): AuthenticationStrategy {
    return new StrategyAdapter(bearer,BEARER_AUTH_STRATEGY);
  }
}
```

The sequence below is run every time someone makes an API request. If above the route, the route is decorated with @authenticate[BEARER_AUTH_TOKEN], the provider above is called, and the verify function is run on the metadata.

```
export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  constructor(
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
    @inject(AuthorizationBindings.AUTHORIZE_ACTION)
    protected checkAuthorisation: AuthorizeFn,
     @inject(AuthenticationBindings.AUTH_ACTION)
    protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn,
  ) {}

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;

      const route = this.findRoute(request);
       const args = await this.parseParams(request, route)
      const authUser  = await this.authenticateRequest(request).catch(error => {
        Object.assign(error, {statusCode: 401, name: "NotAllowedAccess", message: (error.message && error.message.message)? error.message.message: "Unable to Authenticate User" });
        throw error
      })
      console.log(authUser)
      const isAccessAllowed: boolean = await this.checkAuthorisation(
        authUser && authUser.permissions,
        request,
      );
      if (!isAccessAllowed) {
        throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden(AuthorizeErrorKeys.NotAllowedAccess);
      }
      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      this.send(response, result);
    } catch (error) {
      this.reject(context, error);
    }
  }
}
```

But when it catches the error, the status is 500 and the 401 Unauthorized error is wrapped in the Internal Status error. How can I instead return the 401 error?
I have a lot more cases like this where the error is deeper, so I'm trying to have a rigorous implementation.

Comment: I tried to follow this code, but can't.    You say you call `value`, but I don't see where.  And, since we don't have code for `Strategy`, we can't see where your `verify()` method is called.

Comment: That's fair. Most of it was an implementation from built in loopback-next components. The first class is a provider and I think in providers, value() is automatically returned from the class (not entirely sure), but the this.authenticateRequest function calls it.

Comment: I'm totally lost.  I tried to follow, but even your explanation doesn't get me un-lost.

Comment: I edited the question to include the full code snippet as well as an explanation. Please let me know if this helped!